# How to export all rows using Export Buttons of Backpack Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm looking to export all rows of users table using the [`export button`](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-list-entries#export-buttons-1) of `Backpack` in `Laravel`. Currently the `export button` only exports the lignes of `10 rows` showed, and i need to choose `show all` if i want to export all of the rows. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do that using the existing export functionality. Backpack uses DataTables' export, which is JS-based, so limited to the rows visible on the page.

You can, however, [create a custom Backpack operation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations#creating-a-custom-operation-1), that will export all rows in the format you want using PHP, and show a button on the table view. You'd have to code your own PHP logic for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

edit this file

`/var/www/html/omw/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/inc/export_buttons.blade.php`

just copy code on line no-12 to 99 and past on line no-12
and change this

`return $(node).attr('data-visible-in-table') == 'false' && $(node).attr('data-can-be-visible-in-table') == 'true';`

to

`return true`;